# how to create side by side windows in netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans

Is there a way have side by side coding windows in netbeans 7.3?

I've noticed that by grabbing a tab you can often have the window float to a position so it is on the top of the other open windows, but have not been able to do this side by side.

Thank you,

Bill

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just click on the file tab and drag to the far right or far left of the screen and it will split vertically so you can view two files side by side.

Comment: I use eclipse or Intellij, I'm not seeing what you are telling. I want two window panes inside the IDE that are side by side. One is X.java and the other is Y.java. When I drag the tab to the far right, I get a "detached" window for file Y.java - is that what you are talking about?  To be clear, I see how to split a single file vertically/horizantally - I hardly ever use that

Comment: see: [split-windows-in-netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459732/split-windows-in-netbeans) its all about watching the Orange boxes

Comment: Make sure you click on Restore Window button on the top right before dragging, if it is not pressed already.

Answer (score 2):

A file can be opened in a separate verticall or horizontal screen.

**Horizontal Screen:** Click and drag the tab of the file towards bottom or top.

**Vertical Screen:** Click and drag the tab of the file towards the left or right as given in the previous answer.