# Split windows in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans

I'm trying to split my windows so I can have 2 different classes or whatever on 1 screen but it will only split the window of the same class/file/whatever. I've been using netbeans for years and still can't do this.

Is this possible?

Comment: I believe so: https://blogs.oracle.com/dmocek/entry/split_windows_in_netbeans

Comment: only works when its docked. when its float, it doesn't seem to want to split the windows

Comment: To be clear, NetBeans allows for multiple floated tab groups. While it is not possible to arrange the tabs as shown below *within* a floated tab group, the desired end result is easily achieved by having two (or more) floated tab groups arranged on the screen as desired.

Comment: Just want to say a big thanks to whoever upvoted my post. Appreciated

Comment: @zam If you think the correct answer is that it is impossible, write your own answer. Don't add the answer in the question!

Answer (score 42):

You don't specifically mention which version of NetBeans you are using. I'm using version 8, and these instructions work for that version and version 7. I believe it is the same for version 6.

If you want to see two different source files on the screen at the same time (without floating), then open both source files. You will have two tabs in the editing area of the IDE. Click on the tab of one of the source files without releasing the mouse button (*and **without** holding any additional keys*), and drag toward either the right side of the editing area, or toward the bottom of the editing area (depending on whether you want them side-by-side or stacked). You will see an orange outline appear once you start dragging. If the orange box encloses the entire editing area, then the IDE thinks you want to reorder the tab. Keep dragging toward the edge (without going over) and eventually you will see the orange box change to fill either the right half or the lower half (or if you drag the other way, the left half or the top half) of the editing area. Releasing the mouse button at this point will drop the source file in that half of the editing area, leaving you with the two source files side-by-side or stacked.

Here's an example of what it looks like when stacking two source files, just before the mouse button is released:

[image: NetBeans drag to stack source files]

And here is what it looks like after releasing the mouse button:

[image]

If you want to have the same source file duplicated on the screen, open the single source file and follow the instructions above, only hold the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key while clicking-and-dragging.

You can repeat this procedure as many times as you want (as is practical for your screen size), so that you end up with source files in several columns, several rows, or any combination thereof.

When you next open a file, it will be opened in the tab group of the currently selected source file. If you end up with a source file opened in the "wrong" tab group, just drag it to where you want it using the procedure above (allowing the orange box to outline the whole tab group area if you want to drop it in as a tab).

Additional screen shots for reference...

Reordering a tab within the same tab group:

[image]

Side-By-Side instead of stacked (two images):

[image]
[image]

Get as crazy as you want...

[image]

Create the above by dragging the second file to the lower half, the third file to the right half of the top half, and the fourth file to the right half of the lower half.

Comment: In NetBeans 8 you can also use the little "crossed rectangle" in the upper right corder of the window to create a split - much easier than before

Comment: Yes, the "crossed rectangle" will create a split for the *same* file within its own tab (instead of creating new tab groups). The question was specifically about two different classes...which I am guessing are in two different source files.

Comment: sure, but I don't think this is possible with a _float_ screen. You can only split the screens if its bound to the actual IDE. This is possible in Eclipse however

Comment: I did not see that you specified a float screen in the original question. No, it is not possible, but then why would you not simply have two floats either stacked or side by side. I guess it would save a *small* amount of screen real estate if you could do it in the same float, but for me 2 floats is good enough.

Comment: This answer deserves a wiki page!

Comment: Netbeans 15, drag and drop works fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

At least in netbeans version 8.1, you can ctrl + i and write "move window".
This will allow you to move the window with the arrows, it is the same as some user posted before but using the keyboard instead of the mouse (I prefer keyboard for this kind of things while I am coding).

Comment: I have 8.2 and Ctrl+I and "move window" gives me six options, none of which is "move window"